# track multiple human head using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I am working on I am working on a video processing project and the priliminary step involves face recognition. As i was unable to train fisher/ eigen face recognizer models I tried using LBP face recognizer model and it jst worked...Basically what my face recognition program does is it jst draws a rectangle around the recognized face and I dont want any rectangle around alien faces...but LPB recognizer forces to do so?...because it predicts the nearest label the detected face matches....hence an alien face also get predicted as a trained one...:-(((...also does anybody know how to improve LBP face recognition using any preprocessing techniques??

Comment: that might be a problem of how your detector is trained... If you give sufficient `alien` faces (given that it is just not a human face coloured blue/purple) to it as negative examples, the classifier should take care of it... Also, you might want to have a look at [Viola Jones Detectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework)

Comment: What you are doing is called face detection (it is different from face recognition, yes). Can you clarify what is an "alien face", and why do you think "LBP recognizer forces to do so" ? What is the basis of your work for using LBP for the task ? Is it the paper ``A discriminative feature space for detecting and recognizing faces'' by Hadid, et al. ?

Comment: alien face : face that is not given as input for training the model...

Comment: @subzero I first detect the face and ten give the detected face to the model to predict the label..the model returns the most probable label...

Comment: alien face - lol :P      Anyways on a more serious note, a question for you do you want to detect faces, recognise faces or track them in a video? For face detection, I would advise using the Viola-Jones detector, `CascadeClassifier` in OpenCV, for face recognition I would advise the Fischer Recognizer (in [OpenCV](http://bit.ly/STzRkU)), and for tracking I would advise you look into the Optical flow and the Camshift algorithm (in [OpenCV](http://bit.ly/as22G8))

Comment: @subzero My project requires to detect faces , recognize them and finally track them....I have becom successful in tat...but the recognition phase doesn't appear to give accurate results always...untrained images are recognized as trained ones..thats the problem....I am using LBP recognizer model...since I cud train fisherfaces model in opencv as it return an error -1073741819 (Qt creator IDE)...if need full code  it can be found here :  https://github.com/kocchumon/qttracker

Comment: use the trainer which comes with opencv http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

Comment: cascade classifiers can be used for face recognition??..i thought they suit the purpose of detection of objects only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you ask is close to face verification.

The LBP face recognizer returns the confidence value (distance value) along with label.
If you don't want to draw rectangle when alien faces appear, add an extra condition  :-

Draw only when *Confidence score* < **threshold**

To determine the threshold you have to do sufficient testing on the trained models; find out the range of confidence scores and decide the threshold.

*Preprocessing*

You can use Difference of Gaussian or simple Histogram equalizer for illumination normalization.
You can rotate the head such that both the eye coordinates are on the same level for pose correction.

Comment: how can I get the confidence score?? i have used equalizeHist function... is tat enough?...okay lesser the confidence more accurate rite?

Comment: Okay i got it.... but the problem is I cant get accurate results when the person is moving away or from side view of his faces....how can i be more accurate?...

Comment: @ranger :: Ya...Lesser the confidence greater the probability of the trained face in the frame. If you can't write an invariant algorithm then you have to include the possible variations in the training. Or you can restrict the user to pose frontal and be near to the camera..

Comment: I am very new to image processing and all...can you suggest an algorith which can recognize faces irrespective of distance from cam?

Comment: @ranger :: I don't know, but I can tell how to calculate relative distance from camera... **Area of face** is the distance from camera...  Farther from camera = less face area in the whole image and near to camera = more area in the whole image... You can calculate area with the parameters returned from OpenCV face detector -> width and height... After calculating the area, you can do some testing and also search for scale invariant face recogniton algorithms like SIFT, SURF, ....